# How to find all dependent dlls

Tags: .net, web-services

When running a web service in Cassini I get this error: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

How can I tell exactly which file cannot be found? I've tried ProcMon but I don't see any obvious way there to decide which is the actual error in the thousand of lines it generates.

Saw a post about fuslogview - the Assemly Binding Log Viewer, but don't see any log there.

Thanks

Comment: I notice an error in the event viewer too if this helps:
    Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
    Exception message: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Answer (score 3):

I dealt with the whole assembly binding issue quite extensively before and the Fusion Logs are where it is at. You do however have to do some stuff to get them to actually write out to the logs.

This is where I got most of my information about how to do this, and have been using it ever since:

http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can activate the logging as [described here](http://mark.michaelis.net/Blog/BindingExceptionsInNET20Fusion.aspx).  Documentation for the tool is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.80).aspx).

Per comments:  You could also try the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: I've enabled logging but do not see any entries in fuslogvw. I get the error when starting a web service in devenv. The registry entry is definitely there. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you making any calls to un-managed DLLs that may not be present?

Comment: Well that's what I was hoping this or another tool could show me. I don't think I am though. I'm surprised there is no simple way to see exactly which file cannot be found.

Comment: Tried Dependency Walker and it gave two errors:
1. missing ..system32\IEShims.dll - I found it in Pf\IE directory and copied it. That cleared that error.
2. Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
The offending file is ieframe.dll but I don't know what this means or how to fix it.
In the mean time my web service still gives a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Here's a detailed discussion that might be on point for IEFrame problems http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/ieframedll.htm it seems to suggest you may have an improperly installed IE7.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use [.Net reflector] to identify the dependencies of DLL files. This is of course assuming you're looking for .Net assembly DLLs, but not regular Windows DLLs.

Apparently, as a new user of this site, I cannot post the URL, but the first google result will enable you to download reflector application.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using

```
dumpbin /dependents DLL_FILE
```

It shows the dependent libraries at the first level. 
dumpbin is a exe file that is in the visual studio bin directory.